# Site doesn't fill the screen on the iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm developing a site that is 600 pixels wide and using responsive queries to make it fit in different devices. I'm using the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* iPhone */
    .container { width: 100%; max-width: 480px; }
    ...
}   

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    /* iPad */
    ...
}
```

I have a problem with the iPad, though. This device viewport is 768 pixels wide, and therefore the site renders correctly but is shifted to the left because its width is narrower.

My question is, is there a way to center the site or alternatively make it fill the whole iPad screen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can make the site fluid instead of having such strict breakpoints widths. On certain devices, even though you are centering it, - you are going to be wasting a lot of space in the site margins - at certain size screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="600" />
```

More on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Or to centre the container (assuming it's 600px wide)

```
.container {
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Though it may be worth making the site larger in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Why make the site 600px wide? You should make the site fill the 100% of the viewport by default, and then adjust the margins around the content, `font-size`, the size of the images etc. for each screen size so that the content adapts.

You could take [this site](http://tritsproject.eu/) as example. If you try making the browser window bigger and smaller you'll see that all the content adapts (and even a mobile menu appears when the viewport is that small) All of that is accomplished using media queries for different screen sizes.

(Sorry about my syntax)